# How do FaceTime and Push Notifications work on wifi-only iOS devices?

Tags: ios, wifi, notifications, apns

Simple curiosity question.

How does FaceTime and Push Notifications work on Wifi only devices? I mean does the WiFi stays always on to achieve a continuous connection to Apple's servers?

I have older iPad and iPod touches and they don't have Wifi on when the come from sleep. Is that the same thing with newer models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, my iPod Touches' (2g and 3g) WiFi remains on when the screen is off, and I do get push notifications from various things (in fact, as I was typing this I got one from Ambiance).  If you go out of range of known networks and "Ask to join networks" is turned on in the WiFi settings, you of course won't get push notifications unless you turn the screen on and accept an open network.  The Apple [battery life optimization page](http://www.apple.com/batteries/ipods.html) has a little more information, including how to control on a per-application basis what push notifications will work.

Comment: Therefore, you can't receive a FaceTime call with the screen off?

Comment: Hm?  You should get a push notification; the screen will turn on, an alert will play, and a dialog will pop up.  Admittedly, noticing it is sometimes a problem if it's in your pocket and you aren't wearing headphones/earbuds.

Comment: How does that relate to the Apple Support Document posted in my answer? I know my iPad's Wifi stays on too. So maybe its not correct in the Support Document even though recently updated (at least since an iPad has been out, as well as the most recent Touch I think.

Comment: @jmlumpkin: You'd have to ask Apple about that.  I suspect that if you're using FaceTime, it would poll more often from its background hook.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the one you mention from Ambiance is not a local push notification versus a remote one?

Comment: @jmlumpkin: It was telling me that there was a sound catalog update; I presume that wasn't locally generated, although I suppose they could have written it so that it receives the update notification when the screen is on and posts a local notification to trigger some time later for some reason.

Comment: No, I think you are correct. I just wanted to confirm to make sure, since this changed a bit when they introduced the local notifications.

Comment: @jmlumpkin: To be honest, I have no idea whether FaceTime is usable on an iPod Touch; as I said, that's up to Apple whether they switch to "pull" notifications when the screen is off or if that breaks it. In any case, what I said isn't incompatible with what you said or the tech note:  they work, but there's no promise of instant response. If I were an Apple engineer I'd either say "not fully compatible with iPod Touch" or switch to "pull" mode when the screen is off and FaceTime is active, but they might simply assume that if you turned it off you're not in a hurry and can wait 15 minutes.

Comment: It would be nice if someone with a new iPad or Touch that can accept FaceTime calls to be able to confirm to add to your answer for @gcamp.

Comment: I've looked closer, and it seems that iOS 4 "wants" a permanent Internet connection, even if it doesn't need it. If I turn off push notifications and mail fetching (on both my iPad 1 and iPod touch 3G) WiFi is still on even when in standby. I've made a radar to let Apple know this.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly due to how Push Notifications are designed in iOS. If the device does have a connection, it will be pushed to you through Apple's servers. Because of how push works (mainly with a device checking in now and then to say 'heres where I am'), you can get push notifications while the device is asleep. The notification comes through and pushes to the device.

With iOS 4, there is also the option for developers to use local push notifications. This mainly works by just setting a designated notification at some point in the future.

Update: According to this [Apple Support Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576), if the screen is on, push comes on at any time. If screen is off, checks every 15 minutes.

Comment: I know all that. Push notifications *requires* a constant connection to Apple's servers. On devices with cellular data, it's easy since cellular are always on. However, on you don't want to have the WiFi antennas always on for battery live. The problem here is that FaceTime requires things to be fast, preferably instantaneous, so the devices cannot look at regular intervals on the server like the used to (in iOS 3.0).

Comment: Yes. They are not always 'on' like receiving data. It checks every 15 minutes when on wifi http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576

Comment: Then, how can FaceTime works? You cannot wait 15 min. before somebody respond to your FaceTime call...

Comment: I do not own a wifi-only device that can make FaceTime calls. I know my iPad gets push notifications with the screen off. Was just trying to answer the question with a directly link to Apple's support document. But according to the response marked as the answer, it appears that document doesn't match whats being seen.